# how to save toogle class with localstorage/cookies. so can someone check what's wrong with this code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
if( localStorage.getItem("color") == "black" ) {
  
     var classlist = document.getElementById("body").classList;
     clasList.add("bdark");
     classList = document.getElementById("theader").classList;
     classList.add("hdark");
     classList = document.getElementById("sh").classList;
     classList.add("shh");
     var hs = document.getElementById("hs").classList;
     document.getElementById("hs").style.display = "block";
     
  
}

function myFunction() {
 
     var classlist = document.getElementById("body").classList;
     clasList.toggle("bdark");
     classList = document.getElementById("theader").classList;
     classList.toggle("hdark");
     classList = document.getElementById("sh").classList;
     classList.toggle("shh");
     var hs = document.getElementById("hs");
     if (hs.style.display === "block") {
       hs.style.display = "none";
     } else {
       hs.style.display = "block";
     }
     
     var color;
     if(localStorage.getItem("color") == "black") {
       color = "black";
       
     localStorage.setItem("color",color)

}
```

```css
.bdark {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.hdark {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.shh {
  display: none;
}

.hs {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body id="body" class="light">

<p id="theader">Click the "Try it" button to toggle between adding and removing the "mystyle" class name of the DIV element:</p>

<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is a DIV element.
</div>

<div id="aaas">
 <div id="sh" class="sh">&#9790;</div>
 <div id="hs" class="hs">&#9728;</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i want this code to onclick toggle class and when i refresh the page those toggled class remain same as they were before reloading the page with localstorage. so can someone check what's wrong with this code. help me with something similar/alternative to this one. thanks for reading this.

Details:-

i want this code to work as (onclick class change + saved with cokies/localstorage/or anything) so whenever i refresh or reopen the page it would be same class as it was when i left. or some alternative code that works same.

Comment: The snippet errors. Try checking the name of your variable clasList in a couple of places first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There are variable spelling mistakes in your code (declared as `classlist` and used as `clasList`)
- missed closed brackets for the `if` condition in `myFunction`.
- updated logic for storing color value.

I updated the above changes in your code.

I have added code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4nca3fdp/81/) also you can check output in it.

Updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body id="body" class="light">

    <p id="theader">Click the "Try it" button to toggle between adding and removing the "mystyle" class name of the DIV element:</p>

    <button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <div id="myDIV">
        This is a DIV element.
    </div>

    <div id="aaas">
        <div id="sh" class="sh">&#9790;</div>
        <div id="hs" class="hs">&#9728;</div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
.bdark {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

.hdark {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.shh {
    display: none;
}

.hs {
    display: none;
}
```

```
if (localStorage.getItem("color") === "black") {
    var classlist = document.getElementById("body").classList;
    classlist.add("bdark");
    classlist = document.getElementById("theader").classList;
    classlist.add("hdark");
    classlist = document.getElementById("sh").classList;
    classlist.add("shh");
    document.getElementById("hs").style.display = "block";


}

function myFunction() {

    var classlist = document.getElementById("body").classList;
    classlist.toggle("bdark");
    classlist = document.getElementById("theader").classList;
    classlist.toggle("hdark");
    classlist = document.getElementById("sh").classList;
    classlist.toggle("shh");
    var hs = document.getElementById("hs");
    if (hs.style.display === "block") {
        hs.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        hs.style.display = "block";
    }


    if (localStorage.getItem("color") === "black") {
        localStorage.setItem("color", "white");
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("color", "black");
    }



}
```

Comment: thanks friend i was stunk on this from weeks. thanks a lot 

Comment: @fkw  Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it worked for you